# apache configuration - what am I missing here?

Tags: apache, virtual-directory

I have a windows XP machine, installed apache at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2

I set the document root as DocumentRoot "C:/projects"
in httpd.conf and my projects are proj1 and proj2 in c:\projects

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/projects/proj1"

 ServerName  proj1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

 DocumentRoot "C:/projects/proj2"

 ServerName  proj2

</VirtualHost>
```

both proj1 and proj2 have index.php files.
I added

127.0.0.1       proj1

127.0.0.1       proj2

in the hosts file too.

still, when I type http://proj1, I only see the files listing, the virtual directory isn't working.  what am I missing?

Comment: have you restarted / reloaded the apache service since changing the config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from restarting / reloading Apache there's a few other things to check:

First, here are examples of valid vhost configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName proj1
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/proj1"
    <Directory "c:/www/proj1" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName proj2
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/proj2"
    <Directory "c:/www/proj2" >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note how `proj1` and `proj2` both have their own `VirtualHost` directive.

Secondly, make sure the vhosts declarations are being loaded by Apache. In order to get mine to work, I had to uncomment this line in `httpd.conf`:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot :(
the line 
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
was commented in my httpd.conf :(

the site is still not working, but at least the virtual host part has no probs now.

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough info without seeing all your config files, but here are a couple things to check:

- Any hints in the apache error log when you start it up?
- Make sure you have NameVirtualHost *:80 somewhere in your config files and that statement is loaded before your vhosts.
- If you can see the directory listing of the proj1 dir, then vhosts are working and you can tweak directory permissions and properties (index files, dir listings allowed, etc).